# Значение переменной в data AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый день, собственно вопрос.

Имеется AJAX запрос подобного вида:

```
$('.input-to-option-col').each(function() {

    var option = $(this).attr('data-valueid');
    var count = $(this).val();

    if(count > 0){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: { product_id : product_id, quantity: count, option[548][]: option },
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-cart-size').button('loading');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#button-cart-size').button('reset');
            },
```

Собственно вопрос, я получаю в JS в переменную определенное значение, мне нужно подставить это значение вместо **548** в **data** запроса. Как бы это можно сделать? Пробовал уже разные способы, но все безрезультатно.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = 546; // определенное значение
var option = [];
option[index] = "option";
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: { product_id : 'product_id', quantity: 'count', option: option },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
       $('#button-cart-size').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
       $('#button-cart-size').button('reset');
    },
```

Comment: Не помогает, он видит имя переменной в data как просто текст, значение меняется без проблем, а вот имя переменной не берет значение из внешней переменной, а распознает как обычный текст.

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev кто есть - "он"?

Comment: пробовал реализовать как Вы написали, в итоге я вижу переменную option в data, но значение index не подставляется.

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev Вы издеваетесь :)? Где Вы видите? Что Вы видите? Что Вы хотите увидеть?

Comment: Не издеваюсь ) Вижу в консоли, в заголовках когда отправляю запрос. Вот такие переменные передаются "product_id:270 | quantity:2 | option[]:1235". Хочу видеть "product_id:270 | quantity:2 | option['Значение переменной'][]:1235"

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, нужно, чтобы в ajax `data` было поле с ключом `option['Значение переменной'][]`. Тогда можно создать объект отдельно (`requestData`), и затем  добавить новое поле в объекте. Например, так:

```
$('.input-to-option-col').each(function() {

var option = $(this).attr('data-valueid');
var count = $(this).val();
var id = 548; // Динамическое значение

if(count > 0){
    // Создаем объект без поля option
    var requestData = {
        product_id: product_id,
        quantity: count
    };
    // Затем добавляем динамическое поле option
    requestData['option[' + id + '][]'] = option;
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
        type: 'post',
        data: requestData, // Передаем созданный объект
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-cart-size').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-cart-size').button('reset');
        },
        //...
    }); 
}
```